# How do I remove a CAShapeLayer and CABasicAnimation from my UIView?

Tags: swift, swift-playground, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation, cgpath

This is my code:

```
@objc func drawForm() {
    i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(formNames.count)))
    var drawPath = actualFormNamesFromFormClass[i]
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 6
    shapeLayer.frame = CGRect(x: -115, y: 280, width: 350, height: 350)

    var paths: [UIBezierPath] = drawPath()
    let shapeBounds = shapeLayer.bounds
    let mirror = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1,
                                   y: -1)
    let translate = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0,
                                      y: shapeBounds.size.height)
    let concatenated = mirror.concatenating(translate)

    for path in paths {
        path.apply(concatenated)
    }

    guard let path = paths.first else {
        return
    }

    paths.dropFirst()
        .forEach {
            path.append($0)
    }

    shapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.6, 0.6, 0)
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    strokeEndAnimation.duration = 30.0
    strokeEndAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    strokeEndAnimation.toValue = 1.0
    shapeLayer.add(strokeEndAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

This code animates the drawing of the shapeLayer path, however I can't find anything online about removing this layer and stopping this basic animation or removing the cgPath that gets drawn... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: BTW, you may not have noticed it, but I streamlined the code in the answer from which you got this path building logic. Namely, you can further simplify this to just `let path = UIBezierPath()` and `paths.forEach { path.append($0) }`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You said:

> I can't find anything online about removing this layer ...

It is [`removeFromSuperlayer()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410767-removefromsuperlayer).

```
shapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
```

You go on to say:

> ... and stopping this basic animation ...

It is [`removeAllAnimations`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410810-removeallanimations):

```
shapeLayer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Note, this will immediately change the `strokeEnd` (or whatever property you were animating) back to its previous value. If you want to "freeze" it where you stopped it, you have to grab the [`presentation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410744-presentation) layer (which captures the layer's properties as they are mid-animation), save the appropriate property, and then update the property of the layer upon which you are stopping the animation:

```
if let strokeEnd = shapeLayer.presentation()?.strokeEnd {
    shapeLayer.removeAllAnimations()
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = strokeEnd
}
```

Finally, you go on to say:

> ... or removing the `cgPath` that gets drawn.

Just set it to `nil`:

```
shapeLayer.path = nil
```

---

By the way, when you're browsing for the documentation for [`CAShapeLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayer) and [`CABasicAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cabasicanimation), don't forget to check out the documentation for their superclasses, namely and [`CALayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer) and [`CAAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimation) » [`CAPropertyAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/capropertyanimation), respectively. Bottom line, when digging around looking for documentation on properties or methods for some particular class, you often will have to dig into the superclasses to find the relevant information.

Finally, the [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH1-SW1) is good intro and while its examples are in Objective-C, all of the concepts are applicable to Swift.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an animation delegate `CAAnimationDelegate` to execute additional logic when an animation starts or ends. For example, you may want to remove a layer from its parent once a fade out animation has completed.

Below code taken from a class that implements CAAnimationDelegate on the layer, when you call The `fadeOut` function animates the opacity of that layer and, once the animation has completed, `animationDidStop(_:finished:)` removes it from its superlayer.

```
extension CALayer : CAAnimationDelegate  {
    func fadeOut() {
        let fadeOutAnimation = CABasicAnimation()
        fadeOutAnimation.keyPath = "opacity"
        fadeOutAnimation.fromValue = 1
        fadeOutAnimation.toValue = 0
        fadeOutAnimation.duration = 0.25
        fadeOutAnimation.delegate = self
        self.add(fadeOutAnimation,
                     forKey: "fade")
    }

    public func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        self.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}
```

Comment: The `delegate` is a great way to do something at the end of the animation. I must confess, though, that this particular pattern (`animation.delegate = self`) always gives me the willies because unlike most delegates, the `CAAnimation` [`delegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimation/1412490-delegate?language=objc) is a `strong` reference. You're fine here because `isRemovedOnCompletion` is `true`, but you're one trivial property setting away from a strong reference cycle. Nothing wrong with your code here, but just a warning for future readers who try this pattern.

Comment: This is very clever. Combined with a call to setValue(::) on the instance, to record tag information, this is super-useful approach. Thanks.